# transforming json data using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a json data which I need to transform using javascript. The json result is obtained from the server when a user search with keyword. Some objects will be empty and some will contain the data in the search result json. I need to transform into another json which should contain only the objects which has `totalRecords` attribute value more than 0.

I am adding the link to jsfiddle for the json to be transformed. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Xhhn4/3/

I tried using recursion to solve the problem. The code for which is below:

```
  var resultData=data.results;
      var contents = [];
      var get_content=function(resultdata){
        console.log(resultdata);
        $.each(resultdata, function( index, value ) {
          value=value || {};
          if (value.hasOwnProperty("content") && value.content.length > 0 ) {
            contents.push({name:index,value:value});
          }else{
              get_content(value);

          }
        });
      }

      get_content(resultData);
      console.log("Printing the content");
      console.log(contents);
```

But the above code will give me an array of objects which has content and does not give me the entire tree structure from its root. I Basically need the entire json in the same format with just the empty object removed. Can we achieve this using recursion and how to consolidate the results after the `divide` with `divide and conquer` method?

Json Before:

```
{
  "keywords": [
    "keyword1"
  ],
  "results": {
    "country": {
      "general_search_results": {
        "hospitalDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "schoolsDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "shoppingMartDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        }
      },
      "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      },
      "vehicles_search_results": {
        "twoWheelers": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": [],
        }
      },
      "accidents_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 0,
        "content": [],
      }
    },
    "state1": {
      "general_search_results": {
        "hospitalDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "schoolsDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "shoppingMartDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        }
      },
      "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      },
      "vehicles_search_results": {
        "twoWheelers": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": [],
        }
      },
      "accidents_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 0,
        "content": [],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Json After format:

```
{
  "keywords": [
    "keyword1"
  ],
  "results": {
    "country": {
      "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "state1": {
        "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the JSON?

Comment: Update the post with the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I couldn't find any nesting in your sample that might require recursion to achieve this (might have not looked too well) Can you please post a sample of JSON where you think recursion is required?

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle link with the required json format. The required json format is pasted in the html section and the current format is pasted in the jacascript section

Comment: Could you add the JSON before and after examples to the question. Not just link to JSFiddle. You never know, JSFiddle could disappear tomorrow.

Comment: Added the json before and json after format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This should do the trick

I called the function "prune" because the definition of prune means to trim a tree so it seemed fitting.

```js
const isObject = (o) =>
  typeof o == 'object' && o.constructor == Object;

const isEmptyObject = (o) =>
  Object.entries(o).length === 0

const hasProperty = (key, o) =>
  o.hasOwnProperty(key)

const isPositive = (x) =>
  x > 0

const isEmptyArray = (arr) =>
  arr.length === 0

const pruneReducer = (obj, [key, value]) => {
  if(isObject(value)) {
    if(hasProperty("content", value)) {
      if(isEmptyArray(value.content)) {
        return obj
      } else {
        obj[key] = value
        return obj
      }
    } else {
      const childObj = prune(value)
      if(isEmptyObject(childObj)) {
        return obj
      } else {
        obj[key] = childObj
        return obj
      }
    }
  } else {
    obj[key] = value
    return obj
  }
}

const prune = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(pruneReducer, {})


const data = {
  "keywords": [
    "keyword1"
  ],
  "results": {
    "country": {
      "general_search_results": {
        "hospitalDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "schoolsDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "shoppingMartDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        }
      },
      "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      },
      "vehicles_search_results": {
        "twoWheelers": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": [],
        }
      },
      "accidents_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 0,
        "content": [],
      }
    },
    "state1": {
      "general_search_results": {
        "hospitalDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "schoolsDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        },
        "shoppingMartDetails": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": []
        }
      },
      "companies_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 5,
        "content": [
          {
            "companyName": "AAA",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "BBB",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "CCC",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "DDD",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          },
          {
            "companyName": "EEE",
            "location": "bangalore",
            "employees": "2000",
            "reputation": 4,
          }
        ]
      },
      "vehicles_search_results": {
        "twoWheelers": {
          "totalRecords": 0,
          "content": [],
        }
      },
      "accidents_search_results": {
        "totalRecords": 0,
        "content": [],
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(prune(data))
```